# "global var" in ant

Tags: ant

I'm calling one target (e.g `target`) from other targets (e.g. `first`, `second`). Is there a way to define a property (or whatever) in `target` in such a way that it could be used in `first` and `second`. Please don't advise me to pass a variable as a parameter into `first` and `second`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every "variable" (property) ever set in ant is always "global"

```
<project name="foo" default="first">

  <target name="first" depends="target">
    <echo message="${foo}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="second" depends="target">
    <echo message="${foo}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="target">
    <property name="foo" value="bar"/>
  </target>

</project>
```

Comment: Variables and properties are different things in Ant: properties has the scope they have been defined in and are inherited in every task below that. Variables only belongs to the scope they have been defined in. Remember that tasks runs each one in its own environment so they do not share variables.

Answer (score 1):

In latest versions of ant you can use the "local" task to declare a variable as local.

Otherwise properties are always global.